# msal and angular 4 redirect Url

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I am using msal.js to authenticate user. I am getting token successfully. In the redirectURl of azure portal I have specified path as "http://localhost:44340".

My app.routing module looks as below:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'authentication', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/lists', pathMatch: 'full' , canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: 'lists', component: ApplicationContainer ,  canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My problem is when user logs in I do get token and when redirecturi reaches '/lists'. I have a guard. Inside the guard the token value has not been set as page has not redirected. That is why it gives false all the time and I  get redirected back to login page.

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with with the hash fragment.

Although not Angular 4, in my case (old Angular JS - 1.6 app) I had to change the `$locationProvider` and set the hash to an empty string because the `#` fragment was interfering with the `#id_token` returned by Azure B2C AD.

If using Angular JS, make sure you’re using `msal-angularjs` package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angularjs

There’s a note there:

> Note: When HTML5 mode is not configured, ensure the $locationProvider hashPrefix is set to an empty string

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

> Without the above setting, AAD login will loop indefinitely as the callback URL from AAD (in the form of, {yourBaseUrl}/#{AADTokenAndState}) will be rewritten to remove the '#' causing the token parsing to fail and login sequence to occur again.

Answer (score -2):

Recommend using the angular MSAL library example implementation on GitHub:

```
npm install @azure/msal-angular --save
```